# What devices can I use as a flight controller in a Quadcopter project?

Tags: quadcopter, arduino, microcontroller, drone

I know that the **flight controller** is the heart of the quadcopter and a device which has to be considered greatly when building a quadcopter project. In regards to this quadcopter project that I'm working on what microcontrollers can I use to actually make myself a flight controller from scratch? Would something like an Arduino mega2560, STM32 board, Raspberry Pi work? To follow up with this, what would be the first step in developing the flight controller on these microcontrollers? If anyone knows please inform.

Answer (score 0):

STM32F103C8T6 blue pill, the microcontroller can be a good candidate.

- You can program it with Arduino and Arduino IDE.
- Importantly, it is really weightless and has a small footprint.
- Supports high-speed UART and SPI(400KHz) which would be necessary for IMU-based feedback control.

Comment: The only STM board that I have right now is the STM32F103RB. Could I create a demo flight controller application on this and then port the code over to the blue pill? Also do you have an idea on how I would start building the Flight controller? Many of the guides that I find are all flight controller devices themselves and not a barebones type project.